# How to create config class using Spring and share data across the whole code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to create sth like Shared class, which I can use in the following way:

```
Shared.getProperty(key);
```

I tried to use Environment object, but it is always null. Where should it be specified and how?
I use .xml for my bean configuration.
I also have application.properties, where I want to retrieve data from.

Comment: Do you want exactly Shared.getProperty(key), not Shared.getKey()?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Just to have a shared object, so I can use it everywhere in the code. But of course I want to retrieve value by key.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Shared.java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("prefix.for.application.properties")
public class Shared {
    private String str;

    // getters, setters
}

// application.properties
prefix.for.application.properties.str=STR

// other code
@Autovired
private Shared shared;

shared.getStr();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't use XML configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to have properties defined in application.properties file and then you can access these properties using @Value annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is using defining the values in `application.properties` and then creating a Configuration class for example:

Define constants in `application.properties`

```
app.email_subject =My app Registration
app.email_from =Some person
```

An annotated class

```
@Configuration    
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class GlobalProperties {

    @Value("email_subject")
    private String emailSubject;
    @Value("email_from")
    private String emailFrom;

    // getters and setters
}
```

You can use this class anywhere you want like this:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private GlobalProperties globalProperties;

    public someMethod() {
        System.out.println(globalProperties.getEmailFrom());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail about the error message?

Comment: Just NullPointerException at the place where I'm invoking globalProperties.getEmailFrom()

Comment: What about the configuration? My SomeService is a bean and it is also declared in my XML-file. Do I have to update it as well?

Comment: I don't do xml configuration, my working example works with annotations. If it's declare in XML you might need to update it so spring knows it will use globalproperties but I am not sure, I haven't used xml in a long time.